# Context Wait randomly fails / The same "Wait Method" is called two times in a row

Tags: .net, botframework

we've developed a BOT using Microsoft Bot Framework 3.0 with some dialog connected each other with the Context.Wait(Method).
Each post a message and set another method dialog in wait for the next message.

### Code Example

Our Message Controller:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            if (activity.MembersAdded.Any(m => m.Id != activity.Recipient.Id))
            {
                activity.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
                activity.Text = _startGreetingsMessage;
            }
        }

        if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
            {
                var dialog = scope.Resolve<IDialog<object>>();
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        return response;
    }
```

Our RootDialog inherits from Luis:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    private readonly IDialogFactory _dialogFactory;

    public RootDialog(ILuisService luisService, IDialogFactory dialogFactory)
        : base(luisService)
    {
        _dialogFactory = dialogFactory;
    }

    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
         await context.PostAsync(MessagesResource.CourtesyError);
         context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<GreetingDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Greetings")]
    public async Task GreetingsIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<GreetingDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    [LuisIntent("CreateNewList")]
    public async Task CreateNewListIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<CreateNewShoppingListDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    [LuisIntent("OpenLastList")]
    public async Task OpenLastListIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<OpenLastShoppingListDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    [LuisIntent("GetTimetables")]
    public async Task GetTimetablesIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<OpeningHoursDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    [LuisIntent("GetPromo")]
    public async Task GetPromoIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<PromoProductsByCategoryDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task CancelIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync(MessagesResource.CourtesyError);
        context.Call(_dialogFactory.Create<GreetingDialog>(), Callback);
    }

    private async Task Callback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        await result;
        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

Example how we se the wait between dialog parts:

```
[Serializable]
public class AskIfAddAnotherProductTask
{
    private readonly IShoppingListsService _shoppingListsService;
    private readonly IDialogFactory _dialogFactory;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AskIfAddAnotherProductTask(IDialogFactory dialogFactory, IShoppingListsService shoppingListsService, ILogger logger)
    {
        _shoppingListsService = shoppingListsService;
        _dialogFactory = dialogFactory;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task GetTask(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var userResponse = await result;
        var channel = context.Activity.ChannelId;

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "context", context } };

        var luisResult = await LuisHelper.GetIntentAndEntitiesFromLUIS(userResponse.Text);

        switch (luisResult.TopScoringIntent.Intent)
        {
            case LuisIntent.Yes:
                {
                    await context.PostAsync(MessagesResource.AddOtherProducts);
                    context.Wait(_dialogFactory.Create<GetProductsByUserTask>().GetTask);
                    break;
                }
            case LuisIntent.No:
                {
                    var sender = _dialogFactory.Create<SendCorrectYesOrNoCard>(dict);
                    await sender.Send(channel, MessagesResource.AskIfWantSuggestions);

                    var handler = _dialogFactory.Create<HandleUserIncorrectInput>(dict);
                    handler.ResetCounter();

                    context.Wait(_dialogFactory.Create<AskIfWantSuggestionProductsTask>().GetTask);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    await context.PostAsync(MessagesResource.CourtesyChooseError);

                    var sender = _dialogFactory.Create<SendCorrectYesOrNoCard>(dict);

                    await sender.Send(channel, MessagesResource.AskIfWantAddProduct);

                    context.Wait(GetTask);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

### Reproduction Steps

It's randomly, there is no specific step to reproduce.
We experience the issue on Facebook messenger channel.

### Expected Behavior

Always callback the right method :-)

### Actual Results

Some times, randomly, we experienced the fact that the same "method in wait" is called two time in a row... like something is failing in the last insert of a method in wait or something like that....
Anyone have some ideas about that? We've tried several option and workaround with no success...

**UPDATE:**

> Basically we have this situation: RootDialog 
>   -> context.call(DialogA, RootDialogCallback)
>   -> context.wait(*MethodFromAnotherClass1*) .... 
>   -> context.wait(*MethodFromAnotherClassN*)
>   -> context.done() 
>   -> RootDialogCallback
>   -> context.done()
>
> This is working approximately 70-80% of the times... So my question
>   is: it's correct to link method from different classes with the
>   Context.Wait or this kind of approach could lead to some random issue
>   like the one we are experiencing?

Comment: Almost impossible to help like that with no sample scenario, no link between this `AskIfAddAnotherProductTask` and the `RootDialog`. Sorry, but the only thing I could say would be to ensure that your Dialog stack is well maintained (every Dialog must have its context.Done for example)

Comment: `It's randomly, there is no specific step to reproduce. We experience the issue on Facebook messenger channel.` Does the issue only happen on Facebook messenger channel?

Comment: Nope, sometimes (very rare) also on the emulator... But the only thing that we manage to track is that the new incoming message still have the "old" method in wait in the stack....

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to a new dialog in the middle of your flow? Consider using context.forward during your switch statements that send to new dialogs rather than context.wait. You can find some more documentation on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#invoke-the-new-order-dialog) but let me know if that isn't what you meant.